# How to fill an XML file with a random number of items

Tags: python, xml, for-loop

I need for testing purposes to fill an XML file with for example 1000 lines (P0 thru p999) with between 1 and 20 steps and then add the random steps.
How can I do that? I can't find any (good) example with a lot of for loops.
the XML needs to look something like this:

I hope to do this in Python.

```
<root>
    <P>P0<NPS>20</NPS><STEPS>5,19,22,12,0,3,22,4,11,0,2,7,20,19,16,24,9,2,15,6,</STEPS></P>
    <P>P1<NPS>2</NPS><STEPS>12,21,</STEPS></P>
    <P>P2<NPS>15</NPS><STEPS>21,23,10,18,23,22,17,4,17,15,17,18,18,14,22,</STEPS></P>
    <P>P3<NPS>4</NPS><STEPS>15,24,12,10,</STEPS></P>
    ...
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
import random 
NUM_OF_LINES = 10
MAX_NUM_OF_STEPS = 7
STEP_RANGE = 20

TEMPLATE = '<P>P{}<NPS>{}</NPS><STEPS>{}</STEPS></P>'
for i in range(1,NUM_OF_LINES):
  steps = random.randint(1,MAX_NUM_OF_STEPS)
  step_values = [str(random.randint(0,STEP_RANGE)) for x in range(0,steps)]
  line = TEMPLATE.format(i,steps,','.join(step_values))
  print(line)
```

Comment: thanks, was staring blind in elementtree.
but this is maybe an even better solution.